# I have Windows 8 andUbuntu 14.04on my system. At boot it gives "Secure Boot Violation Invalid Signature detected. Check secure boot policy in Setup."

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

I am curious about the reason. In UEFI menu it shows two instance of Ubuntu.Is this the reason i am getting Secure Boot Violation? 
It never showed me boot violation error message before I downgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 14.04 using USB drive.
I can still load windows and Ubuntu after pressing enter on the secure boot violation message.

Comment: Something unexpected probably happened when you downgraded, since downgrades aren't exactly normal. You really shouldn't have Secure Boot enabled anyway, since it causes other problems with Ubuntu. I recommend you just disable it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the two Ubuntu entries with

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

to see what each one runs.  Probably, one is shimx64.efi, and the other is grubx64.efi.  Only shimx64.efi will run with secure boot enabled, with secure boot disabled, both should boot.  You have a third bootloader which might be invoked after the boot failure (of grubx64.efi), /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.  This is probably a copy of shimx64.efi, and will boot successfully if grubx64.efi is also in the same directory.  Zacharee1 is right, secure boot is optional, and with the 16.04 release tightening up on (third party) module signatures, is becoming more difficult to use.

Comment: I disabled Secure Boot however, still unable to launch VMware. Enable to load Kernel Modules. Virtual Ethernet and Virtual Machine Monitor failed. Can run Virtualbox but needs VMware for nested virtualization (used in GNS3).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Ubuntu on UEFI with secure mode then Choose GPT partition scheme for UEFI 
or
you need to secure mode off in BOIS menu to install Ubuntu on BOIS/MBR partition scheme for UEFI.